# How to use lighten and darken of mui on css variables

Tags: material-ui

Currently I am migration application from genral Theme to CssVarsTheme.I am using darken function on some backgrounds.How do I use this on css vars.

```
darken(theme.vars.palette.primaryContainer.main, 0.08)
```

This is not working as theme.vars.* doesn't return color value.